# WiFi Router, current status of security options?

Tags: wifi, router, protocols, protection

I'm about to buy a new WiFi router tomorrow (probably) & I'm wondering what kind of security features I should choose (Like: AES, WPA2, DMZ, TKIP, SPI, ...)

What is the current status of what is considered to be secure?

As I understand it, eg. WPA encryption was cracked MANY years ago, how is it with WPA2?
Or AES? I also have an options for AES-128 bit, how is that?

---

For your convenience, this is a list of what [the store](https://www.elgiganten.se/catalog/datorer-tillbehor/natverk/se-router/router) is offering in terms of router security

- 128-bit AES
- AES
- DMZ
- NAT
- SPI
- TKIP
- WEP
- WPA
- WPA-PSK
- WPA2
- WPA2-PSK

Comment: unless the router itself doesn't have vuln,then wpa2 with a good password should be fine

Comment: All modern routers support WPA2 using AES, and that's all you should really care about, unless there is another specific feature that you know you need.

Answer (score -1):

Many of those are going to be irrelevant to you. As mentioned in a comment, the only important point is that it has WPA2 and AES. Every modern router has this, so from that perspective it doesn't matter what home wifi router you choose.

Generally the differentiation is on non-security features such as the admin interface, management tools etc.